# Is it possible to create variables on page1 and use that variable on page2? (Without the use of extensions)

Tags: mediawiki

I know it’s possible to create a template and have parameters, which can be used to customize another page. What I need to satisfy my colleagues, without the use of extensions, is to define variables in page1, such as end date, classification which i can use the variables on page 2. Similar as the use of template {{:page1|ParameterX|ParameterY}}.

My colleagues want to edit page1 (which consists all the details of a project)
Upon updating page1, they want page 2(which consists of an overview of many projects) to update with the information from the updated page1 data.

For example the project - end date has changed.
So the end date in page 2 of that specified project has changed too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible within traditional MediaWiki. One way to get the same effect would be to do as you suggested and work with templates. If multiple pages had the same information, you could use the common template, *Template:2018 Project X - End Date* as an example. Of course, with many variables, this could quickly become a messy approach. You could also create a template that has all the common information filled in and only requires input of differing information.

The alternative would be to simply have all the information verified by users across several pages.

A final potential option I am less familiar with, but which I believe may have a solution to your problem is using [Semantic MediaWiki.](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Introduction_to_Semantic_MediaWiki) It is a big extension, but a powerful one that may solve this and other problems down the line.